# Combinatorics problem (repeated elements allowed, with restrictions)

Tags: combinatorics

I've a question that I chanced upon:

A group of 10 friends decided to head to the arcade where there are 4 games: Ping Pong, Space Invader, Dance Dance and Race Kart.

If at most 5 people can play Ping Pong at once and at most 3 people can play Dance Dance at once, how many different combinations of 10 games can the group choose?

The order of games do not matter.

--

What I'm thinking of is calculating at least 6 people do not play Ping Pong and at least 7 people do not play Dance Dance, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Again, I know the formula for repeated combinations, and I'm thinking of dividing into sub cases (at least 6 do not play Ping Pong, at least 7 do not play Ping Pong, ..., at least 7 do not play Dance Dance, at least 8 do not play Dance Dance...), but I think such a method will be too tedious and there is a shorter way. Moreover, I'm not quite sure how to sort out the intersection cases if I subdivide like this.

Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: What about the other two games? Can an arbitrary number of people play those at once?

Comment: Yes, there is no restriction on the other two games.

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989068/number-of-combinations-of-ice-cream-with-limited-quantity

Answer (score 3):

Taking players to be indistinguishable, and that all 10 can play the games without constraints simultaneously, you could apply [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Without any constraints, the number of ways = $\binom{10+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{13}{3}$

"Bad" cases are if ping pong has 6 or more players, or dance dance has 4 or more players,

thus # of ways = $\binom{13}3 - \binom73 - \binom93 + \binom33= 168$

Comment: ...assuming the group of friends are indistinguishable ;-)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the meaning of 3 choose 3 in your working? More specifically, how did you arrive at that working? (I understand the rest).

Comment: And the group of friends are indeed indistinguishable!

Comment: That happens when you put 6 in ping pong *and* 4 in dance dance.